# Inserting a toolbar into page using Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, css, shadow-dom

How would I insert a "toolbar" style header into a page using the Shadow DOM that pushes down all other content?

The process is well documented elsewhere using iframes, but doing so with the Shadow DOM is something I am struggling with.

An iframe won't allow elements in the iframe to generally overlap the rest of the page content, so it prevents the creation of a clean interface in said toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert something that is shadow DOM, one way would be to create a custom element and then insert that into the DOM. You can do this in a static way (i.e. have this simply replace the position your iframe would be), or you could insert it dynamically with JavaScript running on the page.

This fiddle shows the basics for creating a custom element http://jsfiddle.net/h6a12p30/1/

```
<template id="customtoolbar">
    <p>My toolbar</p>
</template>
<custom-toolbar></custom-toolbar>
```

And Javascript like

```
var CustomToolbar = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
CustomToolbar.createdCallback = function() {
    var shadowRoot = this.createShadowRoot();
    var clone = document.importNode(customtoolbar.content, true);
    shadowRoot.appendChild(clone);
};

var CToolbar = document.registerElement('custom-toolbar', {
  prototype: CustomToolbar
});
```